# Why is my makefile not generating the .exe?

Tags: c++, makefile

I've started to code on Visual Studio Code (I was coding on IDE before) and to make project I learned that you need to do a makefile to link the file in your project.

So i searched a lot of tuto and i come up with this:

```html
DEBUG=yes
CXX=g++
ifeq ($(DEBUG),yes)
    CXXFLAGS=-W -Wall -ansi -pedantic -g
    LDFLAGS=
else
    CXXFLAGS=-W -Wall -ansi -pedantic
    LDFLAGS=
endif
OBJDIR:= obj
EXECDIR:= bin
VPATH=src 
EXEC=$(VPATH)/prog
SRC= $(wildcard src/*.cpp)
OBJECTS= main.o hello.o
OBJ= $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(OBJECTS))

all : $(EXEC)
ifeq ($(DEBUG),yes)
    @echo "Generation en mode debug"
else
    @echo "Generation en mode release"
endif

$(EXECDIR)/$(EXEC): $(OBJ) | $(EXECDIR)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^

$(EXECDIR):
    mkdir $(EXECDIR)

$(OBJDIR)/main.o: src/hello.hpp

$(OBJDIR)/hello.o: src/hello.hpp

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: src/%.cpp | $(OBJDIR)
    @$(CXX) -o $@ -c $< $(CXXFLAGS)

$(OBJDIR):
    mkdir $(OBJDIR)



.PHONY: clean mrproper

clean:
    @rm -rf *.o

mrproper: clean
    @rm -rf $(EXEC)
```

but I have a little problem ...

```html
xe: cannot open output file /prog.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make: *** [makefile:26: /prog] Error 1
```

And i really don't know why it is doing this

Comment: ok I find the problem at the exact moment I gave up after passing 4 hours on it...

I have changed :

all : $(EXEC) into all : $(EXECDIR)/$(EXEC)

and I remove the VPATH from my EXEC=

Now it seems like it's working

Comment: Hello bragdon, welcome on SO. What did you do exactly with your makefile? How did you invoke make, what was the result? And then how did you try to run the executable? Did you really type `xe` on the command line, as the error message suggests?

Comment: I didn't have any executable. It was not generated. i wanted to generate the exe into a directory that would be auto created but the makefile when run just create the directory and then didn't create the exe. 
And to invoke make like i'm on a Windows computer i use the command mingw32-make.
And to run the exe i use .\bin\prog
with bin the directory that was created by the makefile and prog the .exe

Comment: I do not understand what this "_xe: cannot open output file /prog.exe: Permission denied_" means. I do not see what this "_xe_" can be. Anyway, you understood what your problem was, so everything is fine.